# How do I pass data from ASP.NET to a ASP.Net Core application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

The problem is figuring out a way of sending data / requests from an existing ASP.Net application to an ASP.Net Core.

The ASP.Net Core application is currently using version 2.0 framework.

I know there is a way of putting a window inside of an ASP.Net application, and I have already done this.

The issue is to find out a way to read requests, read GUID values and then perform the logic within the ASP.Net core application.

Suggestions please.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are many data transfer options, eg:

1) Both sites can look at the same database
2) They could communicate via an API

This question is very broad.